# Take values from a column if another contain something

Tags: function, google-sheets, lambda, time, duration

I'm trying to achieve a hard try in google sheet.

Let's start from what I right now, the A structure in the image.

What I would like to achieve using functions like =QUERY, is the B or C (whatever is fine for me) structure.

[image: Example]

Can you help me with the syntax?

I appreciate it so much and thank you very much

Luco

I tried a couple of functions, but can't get to the point using QUERY function, maybe I'm using bad syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all in one B variant:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 TRIM(SPLIT(OFFSET(x,,1), ",")&"×")&"​"&x&"×"), "​"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 <> '×' and Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")))
 (A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]

all in one C variant:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 TRIM(SPLIT(OFFSET(x,,1), ",")&"×")&"​"&x&","), "​"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 <> '×' and Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
 (A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an easy way to do it with just one query or filter. What I did is to create the first column with this approach: I joined all the hours column with ", " as separator. Then splitted it again by "," as a result we have all the values listed, then set them as unique:

> =unique(arrayformula(trim(transpose(split((join(", ",filter(B:B,B:B <> ""))),",",true,true)))))

Then in the next column a query with byrow to be repeated in each row which finds if column B contains that time:

> =byrow(D2:D,lambda(each,join(", ",if(each="","",transpose(query(A:B,"Select A where B contains '"&each&"'"))))))

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cnbfkeuS1LXeD7T6gFVCpXaK2gGtJLvr0-2B3Mq09vY/edit?usp=sharing